# Why does SSMS intellisense falsely flag linked server query?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2017

I am using SSMS 2017 on a SQL Server 2014 database. I can query a linked server with no problem. I'm redacting the actual names, but this should give you an idea of my query statement.

`SELECT *
FROM [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName];`

I get the expected results in the results window.

*However*, intellisense falsely flags the statement with "invalid object name '[LinkedServer].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]'".

Refreshing the cache did not resolve the false warning. I don't want to turn off intellisense. How can I keep intellisense on while disabling this specific false warning?

Comment: Intellisense does not cache remote object names, only that on the local instance. That is very likely, by design, as remote queries can be much slower. The object doesn't really not exist, just intellisense doesn't know the object.

Comment: I gathered as much from some necroposts on SO, but is there anyway to keep intellisense on but make it not raise this specific false warning?

Comment: It's just a red "squiggly" line; you can just ignore it. The query will still run fine (provided it has valid syntax, and references real objects).

Comment: Understood. So I suppose the answer is no -- it's not possible to determine which warnings get flagged in Intellisense the same way you can do with VS Code lint warning flags?

Comment: Lints in VSCode are extentions. If you want a more verbose codelinter in SSMS, you need to download/purchase one.

Comment: I have found that the red squiggly lines go away when I use a login with sysadmin on the remote server.  Wish I could figure out the specific permission to grant as I am not fond of sysadmin, even if it is just a dev server.